EXC_BREAKPOINT when using GlobalActor with unownedExecutor in Swift
I'm relatively new to Swift and trying to make a minimal GlobalActor work, that is supposed to run code on a dedicated thread, using an unownedExecutor as suggested in the docs:
@globalActor actor BackendActor: GlobalActor {
    static let shared = BackendActor()
    nonisolated let unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor = Executor().asUnownedSerialExecutor()
    
    final private class Executor: SerialExecutor {
        private let dispatcher = DispatchQueue(label: "BackendQueue")
        
        internal func enqueue(_ job: UnownedJob) {
            self.dispatcher.async {
                job.runSynchronously(on: sharedUnownedExecutor)
            }
        }
        
        internal func asUnownedSerialExecutor() -> UnownedSerialExecutor {
            UnownedSerialExecutor(ordinary: self)
        }
    }
}

When running the following MWE,
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Test") {
            Task.detached { @BackendActor in
                print("Ok")
            }
        }
    }
}

and pressing the button Test, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is raised in the Task.detached instruction.
I checked the code of my GlobalActor many times with examples I could find online and I don't see any difference for why it might not be working.

As suggest in the docs in XCode of unownedExecutor, this property must be the same for a actor instance and also the actor must keep the excutor alive, as in your code, I check that the Executor has been deinit so an exception happen.

A solution could be keep an Excutor instance as a property in actor to keep it alive:
@globalActor actor BackendActor {
    static let shared = BackendActor()
    fileprivate let executor = Executor()
    
    nonisolated var unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor {
        executor.asUnownedSerialExecutor()
    }
}

final private class Executor: SerialExecutor {
    private let dispatcher = DispatchQueue(label: "BackendQueue")
    
    static let shared = Executor()
    
    func enqueue(_ job: UnownedJob) {
        dispatcher.async {
            job.runSynchronously(on: self.asUnownedSerialExecutor())
        }
    }
    
    func asUnownedSerialExecutor() -> UnownedSerialExecutor {
        UnownedSerialExecutor(ordinary: self)
    }
}


For what it's worth, I ended up with this (with my own queue, this is just an example to fit with your question).
extension DispatchQueue: @retroactive SerialExecutor {
    public func enqueue(_ job: UnownedJob) {
        self.async {
            job.runSynchronously(on: self.asUnownedSerialExecutor())
        }
    }
}

@globalActor
public final actor BackendActor: GlobalActor {
    public static let shared = BackendActor()

    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "BackendQueue")

    nonisolated public var unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor {
        queue.asUnownedSerialExecutor()
    }
}


